# Time organization for an engineer who works full-time and pursuing PhD

Tags: phd, engineering

I am an engineer working in Germany. I got my M.Sc. two years ago, and how I am going to pursue Dr.-Ing. along my job. I know that it will be tough, but I am motivated, and have time to invest.

My biggest problem is time. I need help how to organize myself the best, since I am not only working on my PhD, I have regular job as well. I am mostly interested in ground work (literature research and how to organize it, as well as tracking the progress). I would much appreciate experiences from people who are in same position (PhD and job).

Comment: Does your supervisor allow that, or do you even have one yet? Doing a engineering PhD alongside a full-time job in Germany sounds unfathomably difficult to me. Aside from that, writing your thesis is usually something that takes place in the last phase of your PhD. In the beginning you usually do groundwork, literature research, experiments and publications. So IMO you don't need special preparation. But be aware that you will have close to no leisure time for years according to your plan which can wear you out.

Comment: Yes, I do have a supervisor. I am aware that it will cost me a lot of time, but I decided to go for it, since I think it is worth it. The question was more related to the groundwork, as you say. So, doing literature research, as well as organizing my work. In other words, it would be good to read some experiences and recommendations when dealing with such specific situation (PhD and job). I would like to find some literature or web sites on that, if there are any.

Comment: It is possible to do this, one peer from high school does it, he is a technical manager at Oracle, pursuing a PhD in Neural Networks. However, it took him longer to finish, about +1.5 years. He has a strong publication record, many citations, etc.

Comment: Please also consider that your scheme will add 20 to 25 additional work hours per week on top pf your job (3 x 5 hours under the week, plus 5 to 10 hours on the weekend). Are you sure that this is sustainable for many years? It wouldn't be for the vast, vast majority of people.

Comment: I found an interesting link related to all aspects of PhD thesis: https://www.uq.edu.au/student-services/phdwriting/index.html

Answer (score 3):

I am currently doing my master in information science (on top of the PhD I already have) while having a (more than) fulltime job. There are some advices I would give someone planning to do something similar:

1. **Be organized.** I started to be much more organized than evere before and are using management tools in addition to organize my study times and keep track of deadlines, meetings, courseworks, ... Some examples: I have three google calendars with different colours, one for my private dates, one for my fulltime job and one for my studies. Trello helps me to keep track of long checklists, projects, deadlines and so on. My files, texts, scripts are organized systematically on my computer.
2. **Clear your mind.** Write down tasks and plans. The less you have to keep in mind, the better you can learn.
3. **Say goodbye to perfectionism.** No matter how much you try: While having a fulltime job you will never achieve the studying time a fulltime student has. If you try to be perfect in everything, this might simply demoralize you and if there is one thing you defenitely don't need, it's demoralization.
4. **Plan breaks.** If you don't plan breaks, you won't have breaks. Since you will need breaks to not burn out, plan breaks and days off. Even if you think you don't need a break, take breaks.

There are two articles with further thoughts, one on [idealist](http://www.idealist.org/info/GradEducation/Resources/Preparing/WorkStudy#Challenges) and one on [thefinancialdiet](http://thefinancialdiet.com/5-time-management-tricks-im-using-to-survive-grad-school-working-full-time/).